# how do we add a square centimeter/meter/kilometer sign on top of the cm when we want to find the are of a square/triangle/circle etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, area

```
# lets calculate the area of a rectangle
length_of_rectangle_1 = 6
breadth_of_rectangle_1 = 10
area_of_rectangle_1 = length_of_rectangle_1 * breadth_of_rectangle_1
print(area_of_rectangle_1)
length_of_rectangle_2 = 12
breadth_of_rectangle_2 = 22
area_of_rectangle_2 = length_of_rectangle_2 * breadth_of_rectangle_2
print(area_of_rectangle_2)
```

I want to find how to put the little 2 on top of cm

Comment: What is cm referring to? Do you want to calculate the power?

Comment: nope, I am trying to get this result - 264cm² Note: it is from an external website

Comment: cm refers to centimeters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can simply add the Unicode character to the string:

```
str(100) + 'cm' + '\u00B2'
```

There are many unicode character tables on the web.  The `\u` part means "this is a Unicode string" ad the '00B2' part is just the hexadecimal code for the symbol.  Now, this character is very commonly supported in fonts, but not all fonts, or even ones that claim to support Unicode, have all characters.  Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, I will gladly do that- my reputation is 13 and I will accept your answer in 1 minute, then I can upvote your answer :)

Comment: it works, but there is also a longer way to do it. I prefer yours:)